# Windows Sleep inconsistency?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, sleep

Having a bit of an issue with a game I'm making using opengl. The game will sometimes run at half speed and sometimes it will run normally.

I don't think it is the opengl causing the problem since it runs at literally 14,000 fps on my computer. (even when its running at half speed)

This has led me to believe that is is the "game timer" thats causing the problem. The game timer runs on a seperate thread and is programmed to pause at the end of its "loop" with a Sleep(5) call. if i remove the Sleep(5) call, it runs so fast that i can barely see the sprites on the screen. (predictable behavior)

I tried throwing a Sleep(16) at the end of the Render() thread (also on its own thread). This action should limit the fps to around 62. Remember that the app runs sometimes at its intended speed and sometimes at half speed (i have tried on both of the computers that i own and it persists).

When it runs at its intended speed, the fps is 62 (good) and sometimes 31-ish (bad). it never switches between half speed and full speed mid execution, and the problem persists even after a reboot..

So its not the rendering that causing the slowness, its the Sleep() function

I guess what im saying is that the Sleep() function is inconsistent with the times that it actually sleeps. is this a proven thing? is there a better Sleep() function that i could use?

Comment: Yes, it is inconsistent. It yields execution to other threads for at least that amount of time. There's not a whole lot you can do about it not scheduling your thread's time consistently after sleeps except maybe increasing its priority I guess.

Comment: Yes, try to give it a real time execution priority this may help.

Comment: By real time execution do you mean removing the Sleep(5) at the end of the timer loop? then it would move too fast. Unless i update the sprite by 0.00001 instead of 1.0 or something... and would i use SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST) to set the prority?

Comment: @user2045245, I just looked at the MSDN docs and it discusses how you can get the most accurate sleeps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A waitable timer (`CreateWaitableTimer` and `WaitForSingleObject` or friends) is much better for periodic wakeup.

However, in your case you probably should just enable VSYNC.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually pretty helpful.

Comment: Don't rely on vertical synchronisation, not everyone has it enabled (some might force it off). Instead, use fixed timesteps or make your game logic based off passed time.

Answer (score 1):

See the following discussion of the Sleep function, focusing on the bit about scheduling priorities:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

yes, Sleep function is inconsistency, it is very useful in the case of macro condition.
if you want to a consistency time,please use QueryPerformanceFrequency get the frequency of CPU, and QueryPerformanceCount twice for start and end, and then (end-start) / frequency get the consistency time, but you must look out that if your CPU is mulit cores, the start and end time maybe not the same CPU core, so please us SetThreadAffinity for you working thread set the same CPU core.

Comment: Hope I didn't overstep my bounds, but I suggest you don't post your email address in a plain-text format that can be harvested by spam-bots. Obviously you're free to add it back in if you desire.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I will never leave it on the web, best wishes for u.  World Peace! hah

Answer (score 0):

Had a same problem. For I just made my own sleep logic and worked for me.

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

high_resolution_clock::time_point sleep_start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();    

while (duration_cast<duration<double>>(high_resolution_clock::now() - sleep_start_time).count() < must_sleep_duration) {}
```

Comment: I suppose on a multi-core platform that is sort-of acceptable, but busy waits are never really a good idea. I'm not sure of a better way, though.